# How to get the improvement index in monthly basis for employees absence

Tags: control-chart

I have the following information for each month of the year:

- Total Absence Days in a given month
- Total Headcount in a given month

I want to get an index in which I can compare months and see if things are improving or not. If I only use the number of absence days in every month I will get something like this:

[image]

The above is not accurate, because from 2011 till 2013 we have around 1000 employees added to the headcount.

Question is, how can I use the headcount to improve this and make it more realistic, I know that simple division won't work, I am not looking for a percentage here since I might be choosing different types of absence all combined for each month.